# Здравствуйте у меня вопрос поводу написания живого поиска в Html, css, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

...Нужно, что бы вариантов ответа не была видно, как это сделать ?

```js
const search = () => {
    const searchbox = document.getElementById("search-item").value.toUpperCase();
    const storeitems = document.getElementById("product-list")
    const product = document.querySelectorAll(".product")
    const pname = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")

    for(var i = 0; i < pname.length; i++) {
        let match = product[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]; 

        if(match) {
            let textvalue = match.textContent || match.innerHTML

            if(textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchbox) > -1) {
                product[i].style.display = "";
           } else {
                product[i].style.display = "none";
           }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900$display=swap");

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif; 
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(240, 239, 243);
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    width: 375px;
    height: 520px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow:  4px 4px 30px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.container form {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.container form input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

.container form i {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

.product-list {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.product {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.product img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.product .p-detalis {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.product .p-detalis h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1d1d1d
}

.product .p-detalis h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="container">
         <form>
             <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
             <input type="text" id="search-item" placeholder="Search products" onkeyup="search()">
         </form>

          <div class="product-list" id="product-list">
              <div class="product"> 
                 <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
                 <div class="p-details">
                     <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                     <h3>$25</h3>
                 </div>
              </div>

              <div class="product"> 
                <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
                <div class="p-details">
                    <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                    <h3>$20</h3>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="product" onclick="DS()"> 
                <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
                <div class="p-details">
                    <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                    <h3>$30</h3>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="product"> 
               <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
               <div class="p-details">
                   <h2>Barev cez</h2>
                   <h3>$35</h3>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product"> 
                <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
                <div class="p-details">
                    <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                    <h3>$20</h3>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="product"> 
                <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
                <div class="p-details">
                    <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                    <h3>$30</h3>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="product"> 
               <img src="https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol1/crm-bnrs/bners1/desk_adidas_1306_TV8585696.webp" alt="">
               <div class="p-details">
                   <h2>Tshirt For Everyone</h2>
                   <h3>$35</h3>
               </div>
            </div>

          </div>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: То, что Вы приложили пример кода замечательно, но мне кажется вопрос стоит описать более подробно, `...Нужно, что бы вариантов ответа не была видно, как это сделать ?` — не видно когда? после/до чего? почему? Одним словом Ваш вопрос вызывает не мало вопросов, видимо поэтому ответов еще нет.

Comment: ...Как на пример в обычном поисковике, вот в для примера поисковик wildberries, нужно набирать слово и поисковике появляются совпадения, то есть до набирания нечего нет. Мне тоже нужно нечто такое.

Comment: @Mmgkgm нужно выразить конкретную проблему.. что не получается, исправить ошибку и тд) ваши хотелки можно на фриланс бирже высказать) В подобном формате вопроса вам никто не поможет) у вас даже метка jquery лишняя.. вы не понимаете что делаете

Comment: Значит Вам до сих по не понятно чего я хочу ?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - вешаете на input событие (возможно, input как-раз лучший вар-т) которое отправляет ajax запрос на получение данных по введённым символам и если такие найдены и возвращаются то отрисовывать их

Comment: @Mmgkgm, если нужно чтобы ничего не было видно сначала, так и задайте изначально в разметке display:none через какой-нибудь класс можно, например. Такое решение подходит? Просто мне не совсем понятно почему данные присутсвуют на странице (в разметке HTML) если они не должны отображаться сразу. Приведенный пример кода должен быть хоть и минимальным но максимально точно отображать Вашу ситуацию, чтобы Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос тоже максимально точно.

Comment: По поводу заголовка больше подойдет **Как реализовать интерактивный поиск на странице используя js, html,  css?** заголовок вопроса то на что обращают внимание в первую очередь, ну и сам вопрос не должен быть короче заголовка, я имею в виду описание ситуации, что пробовали, что не получилось, какие есть сомнения, сложности, это не должно быть сочинением на вольную тему, но объяснять лучше сразу чем потом строчить комментарии в ответ. Надеюсь, это тоже будет полезно.

Comment: " Просто мне не совсем понятно почему данные присутсвуют на странице (в разметке HTML) если они не должны отображаться сразу.  " Вот о чём я говорю на странице и не должны быть видны варианты, их надо убрать. Я в интернете встречал примеры которые мне были нужны, да только там эти варианты в JS пишут, а мне нужно, что бы были в HTML, что бы я мог их к ссылкам на другие страницы связать.

Comment: "display: none" убирает варианты, но поисковик начинает не работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
.product {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

display: `flex;` заменить на display: `none;`

Comment: Я это уже пробовал, увы поисковик перестаёт работать - выдавать варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите классу product свойство display: none;

```
.product {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

В if который отвечает за поиск добавьте дополнительную проверку на пустой input.
Если input.value будет пустым, то будет возвращено false и элементы не появятся.

```
if(textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchbox) > -1 && searchbox) {
  product[i].style.display = "flex";
} else {
  product[i].style.display = "none";
}
```